# How to encrypt and decrypt plist files in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, openssl, plist

I would like to encrypt a plist file at building time (XCode) and then decrypt it at running time when launching the app. As you can see, the purpose is to encrypt the entire plist file, and not just some text inside it.
I've tried to encrypt this file with a run script and OpenSSL, and decrypt it with [RNCryptor](http://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) for Swift, but I couldn't find a good result.

On the other hand, I've seen some posts talking about OpenSSL vs new Mac OS, and maybe this command is not good enough to encrypt due it's deprecated.

Please any idea about it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Well, why do you want to do this? Be default, all files stored on device are encrypted. I don't say, there is no reason to do this, just want to be sure what is your case. Btw, a lot of useful info can be found here: https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

Comment: If I am parsing things correctly... I think Launcher reads the app's `plist` before the app starts executing. It may be difficult to decrypt the `plist` in your app since its a chicken-and-the-egg problem.

Comment: @jww it's another plist created by me to store some data. It's like having a JSON file encrypted and then decrypt it on running time.

Comment: Hi, please, does anybody know how to do it? Thanks!